# Extract data from a MATLAB .fig file

Tags: r, matlab

I would like to extract the data from a matlab .fig file using R.

I found some solutions for [matlab](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2951-extracting-data-series-from-fig-file) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172931/data-from-a-matlab-fig-file-using-python).

However, I am not sure how to do it in R.

I learned that I could use `R.matlab` and `readMat("test.fig")` to load the figure in R, however, I am not sure how I could extract the data then.

Unfortunately, I could not find an example .fig file. The only page with a few example files I found was https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/fig/fig.html, but I think these files are too old (I get an error with `readMat()` using these example files). Since I do not have a MATLAB licence I cannot quickly generate such a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found correctly, The matlab package is the one to use. Functions to read and manipulate MATLAB files, including.fig files, are included in this package.

```
install.packages("matlab")
library(matlab)


file_path <- "path/to/your/test.fig"

mat_data <- readMat(file_path)

data <- mat_data$hgS_070000$children$children$properties$CData

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible for you to add an example file (e.g., a simple point chart) so that the structure of `CData` is shown?

Comment: Hi captcoma send me an email explaining your new requirement at gemunu.rohana@hotmail.co.uk  I should be able to put some time to it among my other tasks

Comment: Thank you, that is very kind. But your code is sufficient.